# Overridden font styling - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple activity layout, that has an imageview and a few text boxes. I have set all fonts to Helvetica Light, and also specified the color for each box. In the IDE, I see the colors/fonts as expected for these elements , but when I build and launch the application on my Android phone, None of the styling is applied...All colors are the default black and the font is also the default android font.

Am I missing any properties? Please help! Thanks!

ActivityScreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fontFamily="Helvetica Light" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/whitelogoshort"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fontFamily="Helvetica Light"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColorLink="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
        android:fontFamily="Helvetica Light"
        android:text="Swipe to continue"
        android:textColorHint="@color/lightgrey"
        android:textColorLink="@color/lightgrey"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:fontFamily="Helvetica Light"
        android:text="Hello again"
        android:textColorLink="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The class behind looks like:

```
public class WelcomeScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activityscreen); 
    }
}
```

The THEME is set in the manifest.xml file as:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

as part of the application tag.

Why are my font stylings not being applied when I run the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `fontFamily` with a font name. You need to change the font programmatically with he `setTypeface` method.

Comment: Thank you! I was using fontFamily wrongly,looks like there are only 12 possible cases for font styling, and everything else has to be set customly by the setTypeface method. 

As for the color being lighter than specific, that was due to the theme I was using.

Answer (score 1):

just call this function on your root layout to apply the fonts from onCreate().  It recursivly finds each instance of a textview and changes the font.  Im assuming your font file is located in the assets folder in a subfolder called "font". The skip group just allows you to skip over any group id you dont want so if you had a linearlayout you wanted to skip then pass into the array list R.id.mylinearlayout ... but in your case you want to do the entire layout so just pass in null for skipgroups.

```
public void applyFonts(final ViewGroup root, final String fontName,
        final ArrayList<Integer> skipGroups, final Context context) {

    if (skipGroups != null && skipGroups.contains(root.getId())) {
        return;
    }

    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i != childCount; ++i) {
        final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof TextView) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/"+fontName);
            ((TextView) child).setTypeface(font);

        }
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            applyFonts((ViewGroup) child, fontName,skipGroups, context);
        }

    }
```

Comment: That only works for TextView that are present in the layout at the moment. If you have a ListView, that won't work if you call it in the onCreate method. And since it loops through all the hierarchy, it's really not that good for performances.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute "fontFamily" is only used in API level 16 and higher, what is the Android version of the device you are testing on?

To set text colour you need to use `android:textColor ="#somecolor"`

Comment: the device is Api 19. and that didnt fix it :(